# JSON Schema Validation in NancyFX

Tags: .net, json, schema, nancy

I am trying get a REST API up and running using NancyFX, and so far it looks really cool, and exactly what the doctor prescribed!

There is one thing I can't really find anywhere. I would like to validate the JSON sent to my API endpoints, before I pass it on to the endpoint, or at least before I try binding to the model.

Can anyone point me to a blog post or a part of the wiki, that could help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that, then you need to look at Request.Body and parse+validate it yourself. You could do it on a route-by-route basis, but let's face it - it would be mind-numbingly boring and that's the opposite of what Nancy is all about.

So what I would suggest you use is a Before-hook. A Before-hook lets you grab hold of the incoming request, before it's processed by any routes, and do what ever you wish with it - you even get the option to short-circut the request and return a response directly from the hook.

There are two kinds of Before-hooks; Application and Module. The Application hooks lets you capture *any* incoming request before it hits a route, while the Module hooks lets you capture any incoming request that will be processed by a route in the Module that the hook is specified in.

You can read more about the hooks on our Wiki

- [Application Hooks](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Application-Before%2C-After-and-OnError-pipelines)
- [Module Hooks](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-before-and-after-module-hooks)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi TheCodeJunkie,
That is also what I looked at, but from what I can see, the route it will execute isn't available in the Module hooks. Each route will have to validate against a different schema. So I think I might force each model object to implement something like an ISchemaValidator, and put the logic in there...
Anyways, I will come back with my solution if I find something that I think is of benefit to others.

Comment: The little nasty thing I run into, is that I need to read the body stream from the request object before I can validate the json.

So when I get ready to bind:
`var customer = this.Bind<Customer>();`

I have to first set the position in the stream to 0 like so:
`Request.Body.Position = 0;`

As far as I can tell, I can't use a custom validator, because the validator needs the object to bound first, and that isn't possible if the JSON is incorrect.

I do all this inside one specific route right now. Is there some way to do something like
`Post["/customers", schema] = p => ...`

Comment: I found out that what I really need is a third hook... a Before Route Hook, that will trigger when the correct route has been found, but before the action is taken. The schemas are route dependent so adding this to the model binders won't do. I need a different schema for Patch and Put for example, but they both bind to the same Model.